# Plaid and Stripe integration, ITEM_NOT_SUPPORTED when get bank token using bank outside of US

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, plaid

I am trying to implement Plaid and Stripe integration in `sandbox mode`, everything work fine when I connect to a US bank account. But every times I try to connect a bank account outside of US, the link process goes well, but when I call the `/processor/stripe/bank_account_token/create` using the `access_token` and `account_id` return from the link process I get this error

```
data: { 
        display_message: 'The given account is not currently supported for this financial institution. We apologize for the inconvenience.',
        error_code: 'ITEM_NOT_SUPPORTED',
        error_message: 'this account is currently not supported',
        error_type: 'ITEM_ERROR',
        request_id: 'asyFWRlxqEGLAIN',
        suggested_action: null
}
```

Not sure why is this happening or some setup is needed, hope some one can help me

I have tried to read the documentation of Plaid and Stripe but there is no information about this error

Answer (score 0):

[ACH](https://%20https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit) is a US based payment only, and [Plaid](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#using-plaid) handles collecting and verifying the information about the customer. This is their legacy flow and you should instead use their modern Checkout, Payment Elements, or Payment Links. If you're looking to use more bank debits outside of the US, you would need to have [Stripe accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/bank-debits#product-support) in other countries to offer them. Depending on where your Stripe account is, it will only offer bank debits from that country.